# Rails 7 - issue with Stripe API Create Card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-7

```rb
require 'stripe'
class StripeService
  def initialize()
    Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
  end

  # this block of code generates a token for the card
  def create_card_token(params)
    Stripe::Token.create({
      card:{
        number: params[:card_number].to_s,
        exp_month: params[:exp_month],
        exp_year: params[:exp_year],
        cvc: params[:cvv]
      }
    })
  end

  # this block of code creates a card safely with the generated token
  def create_stripe_customer_card(params, stripe_customer)     
    token = create_card_token(params)     
    Stripe::Customer.create_source(
      stripe_customer.id, 
      {source: token.id}
    )   
  end 
end
```

the above code is inside my `app/services/stripe_service.rb`

so i am trying these methods in rails console, i also have some code to create a customer into the stripe which i did not show in the above code because that is working perfectly fine.

SO THE MAIN PROBLEM I AM FACING IS WHEN I CALL THE METHOD `create_stripe_customer_card(params, stripe_customer)`
in the console,

**expected behaviour :** *creates a card by verifying with the generated token*

**what i am getting:** *Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing. (Stripe::CardError)*

how can i fix this? someone please help :')

Comment: By PCI DSS, you are only allowed to send raw card details if you are [PCI compliant](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide) with the proof of SAQ-D. If you are not PCI compliant, [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart) or [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart) should be used instead.